# To create a directory in Sd card inside an application

Tags: android, directory

I want to create a directory on sd card keeping it as a separate activity in one of my application. I wrote the following code in the onCreate() of the application. It is not creating the directory though this code works fine if I try to implement it as an independent application.
Please suggest a solution for this problem.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{ 
            String dirName = "/sdcard/TEST"; 
            File newFile = new File(dirName); 
            newFile.mkdirs(); 
            Log.d("CaptureTest.java","Directory created");
            if(newFile.exists()){ 
                Log.d("capturetest.java","directory exists"); 
                if(newFile.isDirectory()){ 
                    Log.d("capturetest.java","isDirectory = true"); 
                }
                else Log.d("capturetest.java","isDirectory = false"); 
            } else
                 { 
                Log.d("capturetest.java","directory doesn't exist"); 
            } 


        } catch(Exception e){ 


            Log.d("capturetest.java","Exception creating folder " + e); 


        }  


........................................
..........................................

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SD card might be mounted at `/mnt/sdcard` instead of `/sdcard`.
But the safest technique to get the external storage directory is like in the following code

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "my directory");
if(!myDirectory.exists()) {
    myDirectory.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: It depends. On some devices it's `/sdcard`, on others it's `/mnt/sdcard`. But your suggested technique works in all cases.

Comment: oh ok, i've never seen it on `/sdcard` myself. Thanx for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for the sugesstion. I tried with 
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "my directory);

But the application is still not able to create dir on sd card. 

Whereas when the same pice of code is implemented as an independent application(which just creates a directory), it successfully creates one. This is a really puzzling situation. Please share your insight.

Comment: Yeah I get the same issue this code doesn't seem to work and I do have the perms right too.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of things causing this:

1. Check that external storage is available and writeable before trying to write to it.
2. Don't use String dirName = "/sdcard/TEST"; use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) or [Context.getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

[This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) has some really useful tips for correctly accessing the SD card.

Comment: I am able to create a directory (manually) in sdcard using ASTRO. So it implies that  external storage is available and writeable?